# Can "would" be used twice in an English conditional sentence and still be grammatical?

Tags: grammar, tenses, conditionals, modal-verbs

I know how conditional *if* clause sentences work. I'm aware of the rules which I have to follow. However, I sometimes use *would* after *would* which of course is incorrect in terms of grammar.

**Is there any example where you could use *would* after you had already used *would* in the first clause?**

For instance:

> If I would be rich, I would definitely buy a car.

I know that it should be

> If I was/were rich, I would buy a car

But I am asking for an example where *would* after *would* would be appropriate.

Comment: Would that you would buy me a car!

Comment: I would tell you the answer if you would listen.

Comment: *not implying you're not listening, just being clever*

Comment: @psosuna - Would that you would be clever! ;)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use of deontic *would* in the protasis and epistemic *would* in the apodosis:

> “If you would all **PLEASE** take your seats, we would actually be able to get started on time for once.”

Non-native speakers should probably not attempt this.

### Explanation

The asker appears to be looking for a counterexample to the simplistic “rule” sometimes taught to English language learners never to put *would* on both sides of a conditional.

Normally this is true, but you actually **can** put *would* in the “if” part not just the “then” part **provided that** the first one carries the special restricted sense of *were willing to* or *wanted to*.

- If only you would write more carefully, you would get higher test scores.
- If only you were willing to write more carefully, you would get higher test scores.
- If only you could write more carefully, you would get higher test scores.
- I would give it a shot if you would like me to.
- I would give it a shot if you wanted me to.

The English modal system is much more flexible and varied than simple “rules” are much good at explaining.

Comment: Wow, excellent one, Could you point or give some other would-would examples?

Comment: @kenlir If you would be so kind as to XXX, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, sure, kid stuff, but can you fit the volitive into the [peridosis](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/general/2005-September/024697.html)?

Comment: I don't think native speakers should attempt that either. No one would actually say it that way. They might say “If you would all PLEASE take your seats, we can get started on time.”

Comment: +1 for "*don't try this at home kids*"

Comment: @MichaelGeary My mother-in-law from an Old Southern Ontario Family would have used would there.

Comment: @AlMaki She would, would she?

Comment: To be fair, non-natives probably wouldn't.

Comment: *Would take* fits nicely with the *for once* bit. *Were to take* would perhaps sound off to those who would expect it to convey universal truth. (Now if only you had placed it after *all*. I can handle split infinitives much better than split *you alls*.)

Comment: If you would not assume non-natives' incompetence, maybe we would be able to get some work done!

Answer (score 47):

> I can think of five hundred ways to destroy him: how I would would not be a problem.

Disclaimer: Not a native speaker.

Comment: Other than punctuation, that's just fine (speaking as a native speaker). And sometimes punctuation is a matter of style. (FWIW: *"I can think of five hundred ways to destroy him. **How** I would, would not be a problem."*)

Comment: Just my 2 cents: I disagree with @TJCrowder. Adding that comma between the "would"s feels nicer because it expresses the pause in the sentence that a native speak would natural take. However, the repetition is not used for emphasis (like "very, very"), and the comma is not a replacement for a conjunction or used to divide a dependent clause from an independent clause. Instead, it separates the subject from the verb (slicing the sentence in two), and therefore I think it is ungrammatical. As an example, does the following sentence look correct? "How I would do it, would not be a problem."

Comment: @Geoffrey is absolutely right here. The comma is ungrammatical. And beyond being ungrammatical, inserting it damages the flow and comprehensibility of the sentence.

Comment: @R I think the comma in T.J Crowder's comment is an improvement.  I would certainly use it (precisely to indicate the pause).

Answer (score 33):

"Would you ever use *would* twice in a sentence?"

"I would, but would you?"

The first is mentioned but you could count it as a use. In the second case you could omit the *but* and have the two words consecutive with only a comma in between.

Comment: That was a nice one xd

Comment: The lyrics of "Would You" from "Singing in the Rain" make repeated use of a similar construction.

Comment: For the word would, would would be the answer.

Answer (score 17):

George and Ira Gershwin have a great example for you:

> He'll build a little home
>
> That's meant for two,
>
> From which I'll never roam,
>
> *Who would, would you?*
>
> And so all else above
>
> I'm dreaming of the man I love.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGe-i7mRMes&feature=share

Comment: This is not a conditional structure.

Answer (score 8):

You can use "would" twice in a sentence with no intervening words!

Example:

> One does not ask, as Americans would: “Would you like something to drink?,” because social etiquette would require the guest to answer in the negative.

Source [Basic Spoken Chinese: An Introduction to Speaking and Listening for ... - Cornelius C. Kubler - Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=syFFBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=sentence+containing+%22would+would%22&source=bl&ots=WFLwTTox5R&sig=PPrMsNNSGuLkyTI7j-gPa17Z7eU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6-5Hij-XYAhUHfpAKHVT2BPsQ6AEIkgEwEA#v=onepage&q=sentence%20containing%20%22would%20would%22&f=false)

Answer (score 6):

I realize the question is about conditionals. However, you can have "would" directly after "would" if you have a noun phrase ending with "would" that serves as the subject of your sentence, e.g.:
He tells you that he would never do that, but someone who would would never admit it.

Answer (score 4):

> I would appreciate it very much if you would give me the answer to this question.

This sentence might imply that the other person has the answer but possibly doesn't want to share it with me.

Answer (score 2):

> I sometimes use would after would which of course is incorrect in terms of grammar.

I believe there's no such grammar rule in English that you should not use *would* after *would*. If indeed there's such a rule, you should not blindly accept it, because there are an infinite number of exceptions to the rule as made abundantly clear by previous answers.

> **If I would be rich, I would definitely buy a car.*

Your example is "incorrect in terms of grammar" not because you use *would* after *would* but because you use the first *would* incorrectly. In the *if*-clause, you can fully express the counterfactual meaning by the simpler form *was* or *were* instead of the more complex form *would be*, and the latter only adds an unnecessary and incorrect meaning. In English, as in other languages, when you add an unnecessary and incorrect meaning, it always amounts to grammatical incorrectness.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do what they would do.

(replace do with whatever verb)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can get several instances of *would* in a single sentence.

> Would that you should, I wouldn't have tried what you would have, would I?

(expressing that, desirable as the case where the second person is obligated to act, the first person prefers a different method or result than the second person, and rhetorically seeking confirmation of that fact)

Comment: desirable as ... may be? I also cannot shake the impression that your example should be two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427103/is-there-any-sentence-in-english-where-i-could-use-would-after-would) a valid example of doing it.

> Yes, this is link only: I meant it to be that way because the link leads directly back to the question.

Comment: That's not how we do things around here. Please replace your link with whatever point you are trying to make. Otherwise your post may be deleted

Comment: @tchrist I know it normally isn't.  Look at my link first.

Comment: Hi Loren: I think a compromise can be reached. You can maintain the sense of surprise somebody gets from checking the link by spelling out what you mean in a spoiler tags. Spoilers can be made by using >! at the beginning of a line in markdown. I've applied  an edit to show you what I mean. More explanation regarding why the result in your link is valid  within the spoilers would probably still be preferable though.

Comment: @Tonepoet Yeah, that works.  I don't know why I didn't think of the spoiler tags.  I figured the link was basically guaranteed not to rot which is the main reason against them.

Comment: Nah, don't like it. You're not highlighting the title as I suspect you want to highlight, so there's three possible sentences you could be referring to (title and two examples from the OP), one of which should use _were_ instead of _would_ and therefore makes the ambiguity a bad thing.

Comment: @person27 I'm not aware of any means of highlighting the title but my intent was to point at the title--it's a valid sentence that meets the requirements of the question.

Comment: @LorenPechtel you could copy the title into the spoiler box, instead of the explanation. That would highlight the title.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is this nice tongue tripper:

> How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck would chuck wood?

Comment: That last "would" should be a "could".